# Power BI License

Tags: azure, powerbi, powerbi-embedded, power-bi-report-server

When we try to Add Power BI Embedded machine in Azure console. It asks us to select machine size like A1, A2, A3 and according to that it has pricing

1) Is that monthly price only infrastructure cost or it includes Power BI license cost
2) Do we need to seperatly buy power BI pro license? or it comes pre packaged in Azure Power BI embedded service.

Answer (score 3):

I think that you can find answers for you questions [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/power-bi-embedded/).

In short.

1. The price only covers cost of the infrastucture. There is no Power BI Pro license included. You will be charged according to usage per hour.
2. Only users which publish content need to have a Power BI Pro license.